# Show f is continuous in (0,1)

Tags: limits, continuity

I have the following function and I need to prove that f is continuous in (0, 1) by using epsilon and delta.

$$f (x,y) = \frac{|x|(y-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}} \; ,(x,y)\neq (0,1); \; f(0,1)=0 $$

Can somebody help me please, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $|f(x,y)| \leq |y-1|$ because $|x| \leq \sqrt {x^{2}+(y-1)^{2}} $. Now I think you can answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $$x=r\cos(t) \;\text{ and }\; y=1+r\sin(t)$$

then

$$|f(x,y)|=r|\cos(t) \sin(t)|\le r$$